# materializeCSS label is not working properly with React

Tags: css, reactjs, label, frontend, materialize

[image: Signin Form created from the below code]

**The code inside the signing container something look like this**

the label is not moving or getting hide after start typing in the text field

```
 <div className="container">
            <form className="while" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3"> Sign In</h5>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.onChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" onChange={this.onChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding class="active" to the label. it works for me!

Comment: Holy crap. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the label comes AFTER the input, as per the documentation.

https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html

Answer (score 0):

just add this hook in your project!

```
useEffect(() => {
window.M.updateTextFields()
},[])
```

it is activate the text fields every time when
component first loading

you can add active className on label
but this